# Как std::bitset выделяет память "под капотом"? C++

Tags: c++, память

Читая про кортежи и другие подобные структуры наткнулся на Std::bitset. Сказано, что он выделяет память по битам. Но как это достигается? Разве в С++ можно выделить, например, один бит памяти? Если да то как. Или же Std::bitset под капотом выделяет большее количество памяти, например 1 байт, а потом просто дает или ограничивает доступ к битам выделенной памяти?

Comment: *"Сказано, что он выделяет память по битам."* - где сказано? Конечно же он выделяет память по байтам, так как байт - минимальная ячейка памяти.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/bitset-source.html

Comment: этот класс оптимизирует округление памяти, он не может выделить пол байта, так же как и не может выделить полтора байта. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459563/what-is-the-size-of-bitset-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Выделить **бит** нельзя. Минимальная адресуемая память - байт.

Поэтому он выделяет сколько нужно байтов, и работает с битами в них. При этом количество выделяемых байт, очевидно, не меньтше чем (N+7)/8, где N - число бит.